# OpenShift router with custom template: permission denied

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I've followed the example as shown in https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/install_config/install/deploy_router.html#using-configmap-replace-template but when the new Pod crashed after start with a "Permission denied" to open the map files during templating (generation of haproxy-config and map files).

As soon as I remove the TEMPLATE_FILE env var, a new Pod is started and everything works again - almost seems like a different account is used if custom template is set

```
I0405 11:03:35.627827       1 template.go:260] Starting template router (v3.9.0-alpha.4+9ab7a71)
I0405 11:03:35.630984       1 metrics.go:157] Router health and metrics port listening at 0.0.0.0:1936
I0405 11:03:35.636222       1 router.go:228] Router is including routes in all namespaces
E0405 11:03:35.837826       1 limiter.go:137] error creating config file /var/lib/haproxy/conf/os_route_http_redirect.map: open /var/lib/haproxy/conf/os_route_http_redirect.map: permission denied
```

Comment: You should use the documentation for the version you're using, 3.9. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/router/customized_haproxy_router.html

Answer (score 1):

Can be either one of the two options:

- You're using a 3.9 router and you looked up the instructions for a 3.2 release. In that document, it tells you how to copy the original configuration file from the router that matches your release. Make sure you use the appropriate router version.
- There's a bug in that release (as you're using an alpha.4 release.

I would recommend you trying with the correct version for the router, since in 3.9 HAProxy has been upgraded, and if that still doesn't work, look in the openshift/origin GitHub issues and ask there.